# SEO for bibliography/references section of webpage

Tags: seo, html5, structured-data

How do I perform SEO within my references/bibliography section of my website?  I have used an `aria-label` for accessibility purposes, but I don't know how to optimize for the actual citations.

If I use `<cite></cite>` within `<p></p>`, the whole text within the citation will be italicized and therefore will not follow the [APA citation requirements](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/apa-citation-guide).

Am I doing everything I can for Google to understand that each `<p></p>` is a separate reference?

**My example code section:**

```html
<section aria-label="Bibliography" class="bibliography" role="region">
   <h2>References</h2>
   <p>Hansson, S. O. (2013). Defining Pseudoscience and Science In:<em>Philosophy of Pseudoscience: Reconsidering the Demarcation Problem</em> Pigliucci &amp; Boudry (Eds.) Chicago, IL: University of Chicago Press</p>
</section>
```

**[Following a suggestion in w3.org](https://www.w3.org/community/schemabibex/wiki/Citation_Example), would the following be acceptable even though it is not fully structured?**

```html
<section aria-label="Bibliography" class="bibliography" role="region">
   <h2>References</h2>
   <p itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/citation" itemprop="citation">Hansson, S. O. (2013). Defining Pseudoscience and Science In:<em>Philosophy of Pseudoscience: Reconsidering the Demarcation Problem</em> Pigliucci &amp; Boudry (Eds.) Chicago, IL: University of Chicago Press</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Why not use `<cite>` along with a CSS style that disables italics?

Comment: I would echo @MaximillianLaumeister, to use `font-style:normal` or `font-style:inherit` to prevent the default styling. All the documentation I have seen for [`<cite>`](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-cite-element) tags seem to say that the tag should wrap the title of the work and nothing else. [schema.org/Book](https://schema.org/Book) or [schema.org/ScholarlyArticle](https://schema.org/ScholarlyArticle) might be better semantic tags for works cited, although I don't believe either of them are  really used by search engines.

Comment: You're bibliography is never going to have SEO value.  It isn't going to talk for anything.  If Google did index it and users landed in it the would have a miserable experience.  The tags that you use are irrelevant.  At most just having some external links on the page could give your site some credibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's web developer's guide does indicate that [structured Schema data is best for SEO](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) as

> Google Search works hard to understand the content of a page. You can help us by providing explicit clues about the meaning of a page to Google by including structured data on the page.

Google suggests using JSON-LD, microdata or RDFa.

In a bid to help me learn the correct Schema.org structure, I found a handy tool in Google Webmasters called a [Structured Data Markup Helper](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper).  I pasted the first HTML code I provided in the question and indicated what each bit was, and outputted the following structured HTML.

```
<section aria-label="Bibliography" class="bibliography" role="region">
   <h2>References</h2>
      <p itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
         <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="Please insert valid ISO 8601 date/time here. Examples: 2015-07-27 or 2015-07-27T15:30">
         <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <span itemprop="name">Hansson, S. O.</span>
         </span>
         (2013). Defining Pseudoscience and Science In:
         <em itemprop="name">Philosophy of Pseudoscience: Reconsidering the Demarcation Problem</em>
         Pigliucci & Boudry (Eds.) Chicago, IL:
         <span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <span itemprop="name">University of Chicago Press</span>
         </span></p>
</section>
```

**Notice though**, that the `datePublished` item needs a full date and not just the year.  This is good for periodicals and journals where a full date is provided, but with books, all you have is the year.

The alternative to `datePublished` is `copyrightYear` (books are copyright from the year of publishing) and https://schema.org/Book provides an example where Copyright Year was provided.

Taking the advice also in http://evandavis.org/2012/05/citing-sources-using-schema-org/ regarding publisher location, this would make the structured markup the following...

```
<section aria-label="Bibliography" class="bibliography" role="region">
   <h2>References</h2>
      <p itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
         <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <span itemprop="name">Hansson, S. O.</span>
         </span>
         (<span itemprop="copyrightYear">2013</span>).
         Defining Pseudoscience and Science In:
         <em itemprop="name">Philosophy of Pseudoscience: Reconsidering the Demarcation Problem</em>
         Pigliucci & Boudry (Eds.)
         <span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <span itemprop="location">Chicago, IL:</span>
            <span itemprop="name">University of Chicago Press</span>
         </span></p>
</section>
```